# How to apply Acl to UI component Form in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, magento2.2.2, ui-form

I require applying Acl to particular content inside customer_form.XML fields, Inside this XML, have UI component form fields. So, How do it in Magento 2? I have given my XML below.

```
customer_form.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
 <fieldset name="demo">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Demo</label>
        </settings>
        <field name="description" sortOrder="4" formElement="textarea">
            <settings>
                <dataType>string</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Name</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <dataScope>name</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field> 

        <field name="current-password" sortOrder="5" formElement="input">
            <settings>
                <dataType>string</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Description</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </field> 
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Did you find the solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

Acl can applied on  URL for prevent/allow the access on user name.

***Basically,  ACL is implemented on Action files using***

> const  ADMIN_RESOURCE = '[ACL_RESOURCE_ID]';

You **can NOT use ACL  on form**.***Only you can Implement ACL on That form***

Comment: Have any possible adding acl inside UI component?

Comment: I donot have any idea on this.

Comment: Ok... Anyone know? please help me.

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: I did not get any solution? You?